# Is it possible to work with .NET Core with .NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, project.json

I've been bashing my head trying to create a new project that's entirely .NET Core, a project that is runnable in different environments, but I need to add as references a lot of my previous projects that work in strict .NET Framework (4.5).

So far what I've been able to do was add the .NET 461 framework to project json,

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.0.1",
          "type": "platform"
        },
        "Niloosoft.Hunter.ServicesDataAPI": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    },
    "net461": { }
  }
```

It succeeded in restoring packages and I even managed to add .NET framework references, but I can't seem to use them properly and I get this error.[image]

So, my question is, is it currently possible to use my .NET Framework references without swapping the expected framework (as I want interoperability)  with the following:

```
    > #if NET45 
//specific code for .NET 4.5
    > #
```

Something to take note of, my projects are not supported by .NETCoreApp, so, I do need the .NET Framework I'm afraid, I just need to know if what I'm trying to do is possible.

Comment: Does your library support PCL with Windows8/WindowsPhone8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't run libraries that target .NET 4.5 only in .NET Core. You can only use libraries which target `netstandard1.x` or `netcoreapp1.x` (as well as older libraries which target `dnxcore5.0`, `dotnet5.x` (which was deprecated in favor of `netstandard1.x` and dnx being abandoned in favor of dotnet cli).

However you **may** be able to use PCL which target .NET 4.5 **and** Windows Phone 8.x or Windows 8.x, because their API surface is much smaller and only has APIs that work on both Windows 8.x/Windows Phone 8.x and on .NET 4.5+ (which means: It uses `System.Runtime`, which .NET Core is based on).

If your libraries aren't PCL with .NET 4.5+Win8 or higher, then you'll have to look for replacement libraries and use `#if` directives or target `net451/net461` only and run against mono, no .NET Core then.

Comment: you can use any library, not just PCLt. The problem is you can't target .net core with those libraries. and then you have to use `#if' directives to build only to .net 4.6.1 - and your features won't work on a .net core build.

Comment: @gilmishal: But targeting .NET Core is exactly what the OP wants and unless he has a replacement for the library in question which targets .NET Core, he won't be able to do so. PCL (like `portable-net45+win8`) have at least quite good chance to run under (or with very little changes) .NET Core, because they have a very similar API surface, but `net45` ones can't run at all.